# beautiful soup get html form data returned after form submit

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have a link that is the results of an html form submit:

https://www.taxpayerservicecenter.com/RP_Detail.jsp?ssl=4204%20%20%20%200084

It's public tax records. I'd like to grab all the data in the returned table:
[image]

Using inspect in the browser, I think the table data is in the elements like this:

```
<td class="RPRowData" width="70%">MONROE 1803 LLC</td>
```

When I use beautiful soup, I can't seem to access this td class. I'm seeing:

```
<form action="./RP_Results.jsp" id="SearchForm" method="post" name="SearchForm" onsubmit="return validateForm(document.SearchForm)">
```

Any idea how I can get this table data? This is what I tried.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.taxpayerservicecenter.com/RP_Detail.jsp?ssl=4204%20%20%20%200084")
page

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')

soup
```

Comment: The site requires `Cookie` header to be set with `JSESSIONID`

Comment: Your problem is that this form uses Javascript to modify the page, whereas bs4 is designed for static pages. [This answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-beautifulsoup-scrape-javascript-rendered-webpages/answer/Kristina-Iermolenko) explains it nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the `JSESSIONID` `Cookie` header in the get request to be able to "see" the table

Modify your get request as follows

```
page = requests.get(url, headers={
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=11qfsCuAhlev3j943gEn8bf-CBfH8Ta_z858JNR9w__7PJOfxkWr!-965451614'
})
```

Note: You can get the JSESSIONID using Chrome/Firefox Dev Tools in the Network Tab and click the first request